# Banked curve problem in another frame of reference

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, reference-frames, free-body-diagram

How would you set up Newton's equation of motion for this problem (rolling without slipping in a circular path) using the frame of reference shown in the figure:

[image]

Comment: if the circular "path" is perpendicular to your sketch , than you forgot the centripetal force  the slope of the road has to excert.

Comment: @trula No. The centripetal force is the horizontal component of the normal. It's already in there.

Comment: @dmckee well technically since we aren’t told the radius of the turn or speed of the car there could still be a centripetal contribution from friction.

Comment: @Ben51 Sure. Though the first time student encounter this arrangement is usually the zero friction case. But even with the friction in there you *don't* draw a separate arrow ofr "centripetal force". You add one parallel to the road surface for friction, and then identify the sum of the horizontal component of normal and friction as the centripetal force.

Comment: This problem is without friction. Meaning that it has the "ideal velocity" preventing it from slipping

Answer (score 1):

When setting up free-body diagrams as a precursor to solving a system of Newton's 2nd Law equations, you usually want to choose the reference frame of your system to be aligned with the system's acceleration. In other words, if the acceleration points to the right (as it does in your example), your reference frame needs to have one axis pointing along that direction (i.e. to the right), and the other axis should be perpendicular to it (e.g. up or down).

This convention means that one direction gets all of the acceleration and the other has no acceleration at all. As a result, the forces in one equation (namely, the perpendicular one) sum to zero simplifying the computation considerably.

In this case, that means you must (counter-intuitively) **not** make your coordinate system parallel and perpendicular to the inclined plane. Consequently, unlike a standard inclined plane problem, the weight vector does not need to be decomposed into components but the normal force vector does.

Comment: Yes, I know that. But aren't Newton's equation of motion independent of the frame of reference? Shouldn't there be a way to choose another frame and get the same answer? I have solved this the "easy way", but I wanted to know if it was possible to try with another frame and get the same answer

Comment: @Caterina Sure, just break the weight vector and the acceleration vector into their components.